# Function satisfying $(Df(x)h,h) \geq \alpha(h,h), \forall x,h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has an inverse around every point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ class $C^1$ such that: there exists $\alpha >0$:

$$(Df(x)h,h) \geq \alpha(h,h), \forall x,h \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

(where $(x,x)$ is the standard scalar product and $Df(x)$ is the differential of $f$ at point $x$)

Prove that the function satisfying that condition has an inverse around every point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

My attempt;

To apply the inverse function theorem I would require that the determinant of the differential in canonical basis $e$ is not $0$.

I'm, however, not sure how to go about it. I only noticed that if $h = e_i$ you get that every diagonal element of the said matrix is bigger than $0$ but nothing more.

I'm not sure what more to do, I suppose I'm supposed to either prove that the matrix is symmetric, because then I would be able to conclude it's positive definite and therefore $det \neq 0$.

Comment: You just need to show that $Df(x)h \neq 0$ for all $h \neq 0$ and this follows immediately from the condition.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not sure how that proves anything? How do I prove that such a matrix doesn't have 0 as it's determinant?

Comment: A square matrix is invertible **iff** it is surjective **iff** it is injective **iff** its determinant is non zero.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not sure what you're getting at there? How do I know either of those from the statement you mentioned?

Comment: This is standard linear algebra. If $\det A = 0$ then $A$ is not invertible and hence there is some $h \neq 0$ such that $Ah  = 0$. Hence we cannot have $\det Df(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks, I got it now, can't believe it took me this long :D

Comment: I have stared at much more obvious things for far longer :-).